# Problems parsing JSON with jax-rs from REST API into POJOs after change in JSON format

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I had a working REST Client Class using javax.ws.rs.WebTarget, .Client and javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType for a server's REST service which returns a JSON String. Unfortunately after what I believe were changes in the format of the JSON String I can no longer parse the result into POJOs via WebTarget, instead I get "Error reading entity from input stream" caused by "Can not deserialize instance of myproject.pojo.Entity[] out of START_OBJECT token".

Entries.java:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Entity {

   private String key;

   public Entity() {}

   public String getKey() {
      return key;
   }

   public void setKey(String key) {
      this.key = key;
   }
```

RestClient.java method for parsing all Entities, where target is an instance of WebTarget:

```
public Entity[] getEntities() {
   return target.path("entities").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Entity[].class);
}
```

When using .get(String.class) instead of the POJO and printing the result to the console I see that I get the JSON text just fine:

```
{ "elements": [ { "key": "key1", "name": "name1", "someAdditionalInfo": { "info1": "info1", "info2": "info2"} }, {"key:" "key2", etc...} ], "total": 23 }
```

I'm suspecting the "elements:" prefix and "total" suffix before and after the list to be the cause of all this. I tried using .get(new GenericEntity<List>() {}) but had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON contains an object with data in "elements" field and not an array. To parse it, you need to create an object (DTO) that matches your input, for example:

```
public class EntityList {
    private Entity[] elements;
    private int total;
    ...
    // (getters, setters)
}
```

The important thing here is that the field with data is also named `elements` so that Jackson deserializer sets this field accordingly from your items.

This should allow you to get the result as

```
target.path("entities")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .get(EntityList.class)
    .getElements();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the response previously contained just the list of entities, and now that has been given the name "elements". To fix it, you should create a new java class to act as a wrapper for the list of entities:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RawResponse {
    private Entity[] elements;

    public RawResponse() {}

    public Entity[] getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(Entity[] elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

This is assuming you do not care about getting the value of "total". Then change your controller to use the new wrapper class:

```
public Entity[] getEntities() {
    return target.path("entities").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(RawResponse.class).getElements();
}
```